# Split and extract java string multiple times

Tags: java

I have a string in java e.g:

```
String myString = "MYVAR1(some data[some text]) SOMEVAR(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups] ANOTHERVAR(balloons{clowns} bubbles)"
```

The string contains variables for which i need to extract information out of. What i am looking for end result is something like this:

```
String myVar = "(some data[some text])"
String someVar = "(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups]"
String anotherVar = "(balloons{clowns} bubbles)"
```

The string may also be like:

```
String myString = "MYVAR1(some data[some text]) SOMEVAR(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups]"
```

And result should be:

```
String myVar = "(some data[some text])"
String someVar = "(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups]"
String anotherVar = ""
```

I have tried:

```
String[] parts = string.split("MYVAR1");
```

But that gets me everything and not just the MYVAR1 contents.

Comment: should there be a closing parenthesis after [cups] everywhere in your example?

Comment: Why does the input not have a closing bracket after `[cups]`? It breaks the balanced brackets pattern.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String a[]){
      String myString = "MYVAR1(some data[some text]) SOMEVAR(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups] ANOTHERVAR(balloons{clowns} bubbles)";
      System.out.println("myVar = " + getValue(myString, "MYVAR1", "SOMEVAR"));
      System.out.println("someVar = " + getValue(myString, "SOMEVAR", "ANOTHERVAR"));
      System.out.println("anotherVar = "+ getValue(myString, "ANOTHERVAR", null));
      System.out.println();

      myString = "MYVAR1(some data[some text]) SOMEVAR(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups]";
      System.out.println("myVar = " + getValue(myString, "MYVAR1", "SOMEVAR"));
      System.out.println("someVar = " + getValue(myString, "SOMEVAR", "ANOTHERVAR"));
      System.out.println("anotherVar = " + getValue(myString, "ANOTHERVAR", null));
    }

    private static String getValue(String myString, String name,String nextName){
      if(myString == null || name == null) return "";
      int a = myString.indexOf(name);
      if (a == -1) return "";
      if(nextName == null){
        return myString.substring(a+name.length());
      }
      else {
        int b = myString.indexOf(nextName);
        if(b>-1){
          return myString.substring(a + name.length(), b);
        }
        else {
          return myString.substring(a + name.length());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Whilst this works great, it assumes the VARS are in order. I.e MYVAR1 comes before SOMEVAR.. the bars could be any order in the string. Also assumes ANOTHERVAR is akways the last, that may not be the case. ANOTHERVAR may be at the front of the string...

Comment: you can handle it by change the parameter 'name' and 'nextName' values

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, your trying to extract words within brackets.
You can use regular expression to match what you need.

For example:

```
String regex = “\\(.+\\)(\\[.+\\]){0,1}” // this match everything inside the brackets and match what’s inside [] when present
```

Comment: Not always brackets. It's what's after the bar searched for and before the next var

Comment: Use \\(.+\\)(\\[.+\\])*

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
    String myString = "MYVAR1(some data[some text]) SOMEVAR(table spoon fork(chairs cloths)[cups] ANOTHERVAR(balloons{clowns} bubbles)";

    String myVar1 = myString.split("MYVAR1")[1].split("SOMEVAR")[0];
    String tmpSomeVAR = myString.split("SOMEVAR")[1];
    String someVar = "";
    String ANOTHERVAR = "";
    String[] tmp = tmpSomeVAR.split("ANOTHERVAR");
    if (tmpSomeVAR.split("ANOTHERVAR").length == 1) {
        someVar = tmpSomeVAR;
    } else {

        String[] parts = tmpSomeVAR.split("ANOTHERVAR");
        someVar = parts[0];
        ANOTHERVAR = parts[1];
    }
    System.out.println(myVar1);
    System.out.println(someVar);
    System.out.println(ANOTHERVAR);
```

Comment: Whilst this works great, it assumes the VARS are in order. I.e MYVAR1 comes before SOMEVAR.. the bars could be any order in the string. Also assumes ANOTHERVAR is akways the last, that may not be the case. ANOTHERVAR may be at the front of the string...